# django: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I wanted to make a simple query, but it throws an exception.

View:

```
from callidus_app.models import department
...
def select_department(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    department_list = department.objects.all() #local variable 'department' referenced before assignment

    context_dict = {'departments': department_list}
    for department in department_list:
        department.url=department.departmentName.replace(' ','_')

    return render_to_response('callidus_app/select_department.html', context_dict,context)
```

department model:

```
class department(models.Model):
    departmentName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    leaders = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    logoPath = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.departmentName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things called `department`: your model, and the loop variable when you iterate through `department_list`. Assigning to a name anywhere within a function makes it a local variable, hence the error.

The quick fix is to use a different variable name in the loop, but really you should rename your model: accepted style is to use InitialCaps for class names, including models, so it should be Department.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped.